Wiener measure has no locally compact support
I’m trying to conclude an exercise from Billingsley book on Convergence of Probability Measure (8.1 in the Second Edition). It says that the Wiener measure has no locally compact support.
I know that every locally compact set in $C([0,1])$ is nowhere dense. Also, the book suggests using that this still holds if we restrict ourselves to
$C_0 = \left\{ x \in C([0,1]) : x(0)=0 \right\}$
And that every ball in $C_0$ has positive measure (see Sample path of Brownian Motion within epsilon distance of continuous function, for example).
Now, I don’t know how to use this to conclude.

Yeah, the local compactness claim boils down to infinite-dimensional normed spaces not being locally compact, that is the closed unit ball is not locally compact.
